# Login redirects in Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-views

I have a `auth` system with `django-allauth` library, and i have some login, logout functionally implemented and it works fine. But I want to implement a profile page on my own. With this I'm so confusing right with Django redirects.

I have a class based view called `HomeRequestHandler` that inherits a `LoginRequiredMixin`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomeRequestHandler(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
```

And in my urls i just call it to "":

```py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.HomeRequestHandler.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("profile/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="account/profile.html"), name="profile"),
]
```

In my `settings.py`, I have a constant for `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`:

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('profile')
```

When I try login, I am redirected to "/" even with `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` defined. But if I change one thing in my view:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomeRequestHandler(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    redirect_field_name = "redirect_to"
```

It change my url `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/` to `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?redirect_to=/` and now the constant works normally, why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django by default, `LoginRequiredMixin` uses the `?next=` parameter to redirect after login. This parameter is appended to the URL automatically when Django redirects unauthenticated users to the login page. [Ref.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20path%20that,parameter)

You have set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('profile')` in your `settings.py` file which is supposed to redirect users to the profile page after login but this setting is only used when there is no `?next=` parameter present in the URL, or when the user logs in directly from the login page without being redirected from another protected page.

When you modified the `HomeRequestHandler` class to include `redirect_field_name = "redirect_to"`, you essentially changed the query parameter that `LoginRequiredMixin` looks for. Instead of using `next`, it now looks for `redirect_to`. So, when Django doesn't find a `redirect_to` parameter (because it's not the default behavior), it falls back to using the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting.

Comment: Yes, i understand better now